# switching between ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to be able  to switch between imgCardF and imgCardB on click on the imgCardF and imgCardB ,
like effect of flip card.
here my code xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCardF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#34232b" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCardB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ababab" />

    </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set onClickListener for both and replace the images on clikcing.

Comment: Check out `ImageSwitcher`.

Comment: this is my question how to replace the image on click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first simply **Crossfade** these two ImageView.
Here is an [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html) to achieve this effect.

Or you can directly jump through the **CardFlip** animation of this [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html).